# Passing a static readonly value as a CommandParameter via XAML binding?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following class defined:

```
public static class A
{
      public static readonly double MyWidth = 200d;
}
```

If I want to send "MyWidth" as a command parameter to a button, how do I set up the xaml for that?

```
<Button Caption="Large" CommandParameter="What should I type here?">
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please specify how your A instance bound to the UI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CommandParameter="{x:Static ns:A.MyWidth}"
```

where `ns` has been mapped to the appropriate CLR namespace.